# node.js express 4.4 upload file to generated folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, upload

What is the best way to upload file in node.js using express 4.4.1 to
dynamically generated folder?

something like: /uploads/john/image.png, uploads/mike/2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) to upload files on your website.

```
npm install formidable@latest
```

Comment: Thanks Nikita...I will check it out